# Creating binary for Mocha tests

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js

I have several [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) tests, which I call using `mocha` via `npm run test`. The tests are separated into multiple `name.test.js` files. Additionally they share some functions though imports (ES6).

I need to be able to run those tests, without having Node or NPM installed on the machine. So I wanted to check out if and how `pkg` can handle this.

Any idea if this is possible and, if it is, how it can be done?

Comment: _Why_ do you need to be able to run the tests without Node or NPM?

Comment: Because the tests should be run on an environment where I am not allowed to install those. It's stupid, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with Mocha and node.js, be aware that once you install it locally, the packages will be available in the node_modules folder with a "local" setup of mocha and all other necessary dependencies.

Once you have this you can just include node_modules inside the pkg configuration in the package.json file

[Here is a StackOverflow article that mentions this, maybe it will help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67159832/how-to-include-node-js-native-modules-while-compiling-to-exe)